# Prove that $G$ has an element of order $8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Suppose that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from a finite group $G$ onto $\overline G$ and that $\overline G$ has an element of order $8$ .Prove that $G$ has an element of order $8$.

**Attempt**:

I write $e$ to denote the identity of both $G,\overline G$

Let $\phi:G\to \overline G$ be the homomorphism.
Let $a_1\in \overline G$ such that $o(a_1)=8$ .Then $\exists a\in G$ such that $\phi(a)=a_1$.

Now $a_1^8=e\implies \phi(a)^8=e\implies \phi(a^8)=e=\phi(e)$.

How to proceed after this?

Comment: I think you mean to say that $o(a_1)=8$?

Comment: Also a hint: Use the property of a homomorphism which states that the identity maps to the identity.

Comment: So far, your argument proves that 8 divides the order of $a$ and that $a^8 \in \mathrm{ker}(\phi)$.  I've tried, but it's hard to get that the order of $a$ is exactly 8.  (I've also tried to construct a counterexample, but have failed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your argument.  We know* that $8$ divides the order of $a$, so write $\mathrm{ord}(a) = 8k$ for (the only possible) integer $k \geq 1$.  Then the element $a^k \in G$ has order 8.  (Certainly $8$ kills $a^k$, and if anything smaller did this would contradict the order of $a$ being $8k$.)

(*)  If you didn't know this, it follows from Lagrange.  Any homomorphism $\theta: G \to L$ (surjective or not, it doesn't matter) has the property that $\mathrm{ord}(\theta(a))$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ for each $a \in G$ of finite order.

Comment: +1, nice answer. (If you happened to see my previous comment, I was mistaken.)

Answer (score 0):

If $f: G_1 → G_2$ is homomorphism and  $a∈G_1$ then $o(f(a)) | o(a)$ where $o(a)$ denotes the order of $a$.

Here as, as given that $a_1 ∈ G_2$ has order $8$ that is, $o(a_1) = 8$.  As homomorphism is onto so there must be some $a∈G_1$ such that $f(a) = a_1$.

But order $o(f(a)) | o(a)$

$→ o(a_1) | o(a)$

$→ o(a) = 8k$  where k is positive integer. 
Hence it follows that, $G_1$ has element of order $8$